# Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implication of Facebook offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798085/implication-of-facebook-offline-access-deprecation)

I am posting this problem here because I couldn't find an answer anywhere for my specific case.

I have created a server-side PHP app that posts/showcases automatically on our FB fan page every week a link to one of our products, randomly.

This script has worked great until 10 days ago, now we get the following error when we call the script manually:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1355862507. The current unix time is 1356217401. thrown in /home/webadmin/virtualsheetmusic.com/html/facebook/API/base_facebook.php on line 1249
```

Now, I have figured out that the problem is in the passed access_token, but I can't find out how to generate a new one in the format I am using with this application.

Here is the token format we have been using so far:

`$fanpagetoken = '<REMOVED ACCESS TOKEN FROM TEXT>';`

And here is the PHP code we are using for posting on our wall:

```
    #Define vars...
$day = strtotime($today);
$day = date("l, F j, Y", $day);

$deadline = strtotime("+1 week");
$deadline = date("l, F j, Y", $deadline);

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appid,
  'secret' => $secret,
));



$attachment = array(
                    'access_token' => $fanpagetoken,

                    'message' => "Sheet Music Showcase for ".$day.":",
                    'name' => $headline,
                    'caption' => "Showcase Expiration: $deadline",
                    'link' => 'http://www.ourwebsite.com/s/'.$createsession,
                    'description' => 'View the complete high quality PDF sheet music file, listen to related audio files and more!',
                    'picture' => 'http://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/images/icons/new_downloadsHome/'.$mainid.'.gif',
                    'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Learn more...', 
                                      'link' => 'http://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/s/'.$createsession))
                    );


$result = $facebook->api('/oursitefanpage/feed/',
                            'post',
                            $attachment);
```

How to generate a new token in that format?

Any help is very welcome!

Thank you in advance for any thoughts

Best,
Fab.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a never expiring token for your fan page. Follow the simple steps:

1. Get the admin's(i.e. yours) extended token (2 months validity). Go though the link to get the extended token. Works with perfection:

   [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation/9035036#9035036)
2. Using this token, Get the list of pages/apps-

   ```
   $facebook->api("/USER_ID/accounts");
   ```
3. Get the never expiring access token for any page-

   ```
   $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
   ```

(You can use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the validity of the token.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but looks like I am having problems right at your suggested first step.

Comment: I have tried to call the extended access token with:


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => $appid,
   'secret' => $secret,
 ));

$exttk = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();


After adding the function to the Facebook class, but I don't get back anything inside the $exttk variable... any ideas?


Thanks!

Comment: There must be some error in your code. Btw, you can check directly by running this in your browser: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    fb_exchange_token=SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: exchange APP_ID, APP_SECRET and SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN carefully!