# Facebook Graph Api: access address

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm currently testing my app on facebook trying to access my accounts address.

In the graph explorer it says:

> field is empty or disallowed by access token.

I checked all access rights and entered an address in my profile.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer trying to get:

```
/me?fields=picture.height(200).width(150),name,gender,languages,location,about,ad‌​dress
```

for `address` it says: `field is empty or disallowed by access token`; name etc. works fine.

Got a token for:

> email, user_about_me, user_actions.books, user_actions.music, user_actions.news, user_actions.video, user_activities, user_birthday, user_checkins, user_education_history, user_events, user_friends, user_games_activity, user_groups, user_hometown, user_interests, user_likes, user_location, user_notes, user_online_presence, user_photo_video_tags, user_photos, user_questions, user_relationship_details, user_relationships, user_religion_politics, user_status, user_subscriptions, user_videos, user_website, user_work_history

Comment: Suggestion: Describe the problem so that we actually can see what you’ve done …

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer trying to get: me?fields=picture.height(200).width(150),name,gender,languages,location,about,address for adress it says: field is empty or disallowed by access token. || Edited post for further information

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798085/implication-of-facebook-offline-access-deprecation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user address is not accessible via API.  Earlier it was accessible with permission `user_address`, but they've removed this know.

See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/) blog post.